# httpInterceptor Angularjs: change $http request files to requirejs

Tags: angularjs, interceptor

```
   $provide.factory('myHttpInterceptor', function($q) {
            return {
                // optional method
                'request': function(config) {
                    return config;
                },
                // optional method
                'requestError': function(rejection) {
                    // do something on error
                    console.log(config);
                    return $q.reject(rejection);
                },
                // optional method
                'response': function(response) {
                    // do something on success

                    return response;
                },
                // optional method
                'responseError': function(rejection) {
                    // do something on error
                    //if (canRecover(rejection)) {
                    //    return responseOrNewPromise;
                    //}
                    return $q.reject(rejection);
                }
            };
        });

        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('myHttpInterceptor');
```

I want when client request file '.html', it won't call to server ever. Instead I will use requireJS. How can I response this data from requirejs to client?